# Setting Page Height

Tags: css, height

Hello fellow earthlings,
I have an image as my background that I created in photoshop.  The image has a height of 2500px.  I am wanting the page to have a height of 1500px.  Basically, there is a lot of blank space at the bottom of the page so I am trying to shrink it.  I have tested a number of things, but have had no luck.  I was wondering if someone could help me.  Here is what the css for the body looks like:

```
.body
{
    background-image: url(final2.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Live Long and Prosper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you apply the style to the correct element?

There is a difference between this:

```
.body {
    background-image: url(final2.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

and this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(final2.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

In the first (your current code) you style *something* with a class of body, while the second piece of code will style the `body` element. See the little dot :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try anything like this?

```
.body
{
    background-image: url(final2.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 1500px;
}
```